# "angular-file-upload.js" file uploading using 'node.js'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am using well known `angular-file-upload.js` module to upload files.

At this example:

```
'use strict';


angular


.module('app', ['angularFileUpload'])


.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'upload.php'
    });

    // FILTERS

    uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'imageFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
            return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
        }
    });

    // CALLBACKS

    uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
        console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
    };
    uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
        console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
    };
    uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
        console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
    };
    uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
        console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
    };
    uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
        console.info('onCompleteAll');
    };

    console.info('uploader', uploader);
}]);
```

this line of code `url: 'upload.php'` sends requests to some `php` file.

Instead of `php` I use `node.js`.

To make it work then, I created some `app.js` file with:

```
app.post('/loadFiles', function (request, response) {
    response.send(200, { result: "ok" });
});
```

and changed controller's code to `url: '/loadFiles'`.

I can see that this route is being called but I do not know how to get images from `request` here.

After a couple of hours of googling, it appears to me that I should somehow encode images into `item` on `uploader.onBeforeUploadItem` event in controller (and then somehow decode images on server side) but I did not manage to find a complete example and decided to ask for your help.

Could you please point out what is the server side (or maybe also controller side) code to get images passed from user's browser to server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I figured out:

There is nothing to be done within `uploader.onBeforeUploadItem`.

All I had to do to get into files on server side was:

```
app.post('/loadFiles', multipartyMiddleware, function (req, res) {
    var file = req.files.file;
   console.log(file.name);
   console.log(file.type);
   console.log(file.path);

   res.send(200, { result: "ok" });
});


var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();
```